# Add image title in textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, append, image, title

I need solution for adding `<img> tag title=""` into `textarea`, but without removing any existing text. Just like `.after();` or `.append();`.
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XrKuy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native javascript selector:

```
document.getElementById('message').value += ' '+title+' ';
```

then it works fine.

Here is your jsFiddle with this solution:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kay82/XrKuy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `$('textarea').append(' '+title+' ');` instead of `$('textarea').val(' '+title+' ');`